# How can I make sure my deleted_at field gets set to NULL on save in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When saving my object with SoftDeletingTrait, my database field 'deleted_at' always gets set to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' instead of NULL value. I'm using the latest Laravel 5.0 build.

My object:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;


class Entity extends Eloquent{

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $fillable = array('title');

}
```

My save call:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Entity;
    try{
        $data = ['title' => 'Test'];
        $entity->fill($data);
        $entity->save();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The 'deleted_at' field in the database DOES allow NULL values, so that's not the problem. When querying the model, it doesn't retrieve the records, since the field is not null. How can I change this?

Comment: It *allows* null values, but is that the *default* value? What does your `Schema` look like for the table?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your schema / migration for the Entity table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value might be incorrect. Proper columns for soft-delete-functionality are set up in your `Schema` like this:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

Comment: Thanks, for some weird reason my table got the default value '0000-00-00 00:00:00', even though NULL was enabled.. Had to make sure both NULL (as option) and NULL (as default value) where set. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

You should also manually add the deleted_at column to your dates property, if you want to take advantage of `Carbon` date features:

```
class Entity extends Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    // add this line:
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    //
    protected $fillable = array('title');
}
```

(Laravel's 4.1->4.2 upgrade docs state that you *must* do this, but it's apparently not necessary for soft deletes to function.)

Comment: I don't think this is true. `$dates` tells Laravel which items to turn into `Carbon` objects (with the handy date handling it adds) when accessing those attributes, but it's not necessary for soft deletion to work. I just checked (L4.2) in a model with soft deletes and no `$dates` set and it works fine.

Comment: Then the 4.1-4.2 upgrade docs that currently state "You must also manually add the `deleted_at` column to your `dates` property" should be changed, if Carbonizing `deleted_at` isn't actually necessary. For a short time, `deleted_at` was included in the array of dates that were automatically Carbonized (along with `created_at` and `updated`at`), but that was changed when the `$dates` property was re-introduced. But you are correct, adding it to `$dates` doesn't appear to be a requirement for soft deletes to function.

Comment: Edited answer to change 'must' to 'should'.

Comment: In Laravel 5.2, I was not able to create an Eloquent object and save deleted_at as null without ```projected $dates = ['deleted_at']```.

Answer (score -2):

You have 2 wayes of doing this:

either you set the deleted_at specifically to null in the database (as a default value) -> RECOMANDED

or you can do something like `$data = ['title' => 'Test', 'deleted_at' => NULL];`